# Strange DNS resolution in WSL2 and VPN connected

Tags: vpn, dns, wsl2

I'm running a WSL2, Ubuntu 22, within Windows 10. When I `nslookup` without connecting to VPN, I get the following results (note that all answers are different IP addresses for the FQDN google.com).

```
daniel@DESKTOP-6M0RKK1:~
⤷ nslookup google.com
Server:         172.23.144.1
Address:        172.23.144.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.251.116.139
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.251.116.102
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.251.116.100
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.251.116.113
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.251.116.101
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.251.116.138
```

However, when I connect to VPN, the answers changes, showing also answers of IP addresses of some DNS servers.

```
daniel@DESKTOP-6M0RKK1:~
⤷ nslookup google.com
Server:         172.23.144.1
Address:        172.23.144.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.251.135.110
Name:   ns1.google.com
Address: 216.239.32.10
Name:   ns2.google.com
Address: 216.239.34.10
Name:   ns3.google.com
Address: 216.239.36.10
Name:   ns4.google.com
Address: 216.239.38.10
```

I am showing the example with `google.com`, but that's happening with any URL I try to lookup. And this is the symptom, the true problem is the other commands (like `curl`) are using a random(?) IP from the resolution list when requesting, and sometimes the request goes to the first IP, running successfully, but other times the request end up being made to the DNS servers instead of the correct IP.

Right now I have no idea where to check for problems. I don't know if the problem is a misconfiguration on WSL, or on Windows networking, or maybe on VPN's DNS server. So any kind of help is very much appreciated.

Ps.: The resolution from Windows directly works fine with the VPN connected. The problem is only inside WSL.

---

Edit: Adding debug output. It looks like `Authority` and `Additional` records are being merged with `Answers` when the lookup uses the WSL interface gateway as nameserver.

###### Output of `nslookup -debug google.com` from WSL2 system.

This command should use the WSL gateway as nameserver and will them send the request to VPN nameserver.

```
daniel@DESKTOP-6M0RKK1:~
⤷ nslookup -debug google.com
Server:         172.23.144.1
Address:        172.23.144.1#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
        google.com, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  google.com
        internet address = 142.251.133.174
        ttl = 0
    ->  ns1.google.com
        internet address = 216.239.32.10
        ttl = 0
    ->  ns2.google.com
        internet address = 216.239.34.10
        ttl = 0
    ->  ns3.google.com
        internet address = 216.239.36.10
        ttl = 0
    ->  ns4.google.com
        internet address = 216.239.38.10
        ttl = 0
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.251.133.174
Name:   ns1.google.com
Address: 216.239.32.10
Name:   ns2.google.com
Address: 216.239.34.10
Name:   ns3.google.com
Address: 216.239.36.10
Name:   ns4.google.com
Address: 216.239.38.10
```

###### Output of `nslookup -debug google.com 10.0.24.151` from WSL2 system.

This command should use the VPN nameserver directly.

```
daniel@DESKTOP-6M0RKK1:~
⤷ nslookup -debug google.com 10.0.24.151
Server:         10.0.24.151
Address:        10.0.24.151#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
        google.com, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  google.com
        internet address = 142.251.133.174
        ttl = 227
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  google.com
        nameserver = ns1.google.com.
        ttl = 5636
    ->  google.com
        nameserver = ns2.google.com.
        ttl = 5636
    ->  google.com
        nameserver = ns4.google.com.
        ttl = 5636
    ->  google.com
        nameserver = ns3.google.com.
        ttl = 5636
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
    ->  ns1.google.com
        internet address = 216.239.32.10
        ttl = 92272
    ->  ns2.google.com
        internet address = 216.239.34.10
        ttl = 92272
    ->  ns3.google.com
        internet address = 216.239.36.10
        ttl = 18575
    ->  ns4.google.com
        internet address = 216.239.38.10
        ttl = 18575
------------
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.251.133.174
```

###### Output of `nslookup -d google.com` from Windows.

This command should use the VPN nameserver directly. The output was redacted to not show names related to the company I work for.

```
PS C:\Users\danie> nslookup -d google.com
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 7,  additional = 7

    QUESTIONS:
        151.24.0.10.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  151.24.0.10.in-addr.arpa
        name = s2-<redacted>
        ttl = 900 (15 mins)
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  10.in-addr.arpa
        nameserver = s17-<redacted>
        ttl = 900 (15 mins)
    ->  10.in-addr.arpa
        nameserver = s343-<redacted>
        ttl = 900 (15 mins)
    ->  10.in-addr.arpa
        nameserver = s2-<redacted>
        ttl = 900 (15 mins)
    ->  10.in-addr.arpa
        nameserver = s344-<redacted>
        ttl = 900 (15 mins)
    ->  10.in-addr.arpa
        nameserver = s1-<redacted>
        ttl = 900 (15 mins)
    ->  10.in-addr.arpa
        nameserver = <redacted>
        ttl = 900 (15 mins)
    ->  10.in-addr.arpa
        nameserver = <redacted>
        ttl = 900 (15 mins)
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
    ->  s1-<redacted>
        internet address = 10.0.16.253
        ttl = 900 (15 mins)
    ->  <redacted>
        internet address = 10.17.0.4
        ttl = 900 (15 mins)
    ->  s17-<redacted>
        internet address = 10.8.74.34
        ttl = 900 (15 mins)
    ->  <redacted>
        internet address = 10.58.0.240
        ttl = 900 (15 mins)
    ->  s2-<redacted>
        internet address = 10.0.24.151
        ttl = 900 (15 mins)
    ->  s343-<redacted>
        internet address = 10.0.29.143
        ttl = 900 (15 mins)
    ->  s344-<redacted>
        internet address = 10.0.29.144
        ttl = 900 (15 mins)

------------
Server:  s2-<redacted>
Address:  10.0.24.151

------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        google.com.<redated_internal_suffix>, type = A, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  <redated_internal_suffix>
        ttl = 900 (15 mins)
        primary name server = s2-<redacted>.<redated_internal_suffix>
        responsible mail addr = root.s2-<redacted>
        serial  = 2023071101
        refresh = 86400 (1 day)
        retry   = 7200 (2 hours)
        expire  = 2592000 (30 days)
        default TTL = 345600 (4 days)

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        google.com.<redated_internal_suffix>, type = AAAA, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  <redated_internal_suffix>
        ttl = 900 (15 mins)
        primary name server = s2-<redacted>
        responsible mail addr = root.s2-<redacted>
        serial  = 2023071101
        refresh = 86400 (1 day)
        retry   = 7200 (2 hours)
        expire  = 2592000 (30 days)
        default TTL = 345600 (4 days)

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 4, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 4,  additional = 8

    QUESTIONS:
        google.com, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  google.com
        internet address = 142.250.79.14
        ttl = 23 (23 secs)
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  google.com
        nameserver = ns2.google.com
        ttl = 6075 (1 hour 41 mins 15 secs)
    ->  google.com
        nameserver = ns4.google.com
        ttl = 6075 (1 hour 41 mins 15 secs)
    ->  google.com
        nameserver = ns3.google.com
        ttl = 6075 (1 hour 41 mins 15 secs)
    ->  google.com
        nameserver = ns1.google.com
        ttl = 6075 (1 hour 41 mins 15 secs)
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
    ->  ns1.google.com
        internet address = 216.239.32.10
        ttl = 92711 (1 day 1 hour 45 mins 11 secs)
    ->  ns2.google.com
        internet address = 216.239.34.10
        ttl = 92711 (1 day 1 hour 45 mins 11 secs)
    ->  ns3.google.com
        internet address = 216.239.36.10
        ttl = 19014 (5 hours 16 mins 54 secs)
    ->  ns4.google.com
        internet address = 216.239.38.10
        ttl = 19014 (5 hours 16 mins 54 secs)
    ->  ns1.google.com
        AAAA IPv6 address = 2001:4860:4802:32::a
        ttl = 160225 (1 day 20 hours 30 mins 25 secs)
    ->  ns2.google.com
        AAAA IPv6 address = 2001:4860:4802:34::a
        ttl = 160225 (1 day 20 hours 30 mins 25 secs)
    ->  ns3.google.com
        AAAA IPv6 address = 2001:4860:4802:36::a
        ttl = 160225 (1 day 20 hours 30 mins 25 secs)
    ->  ns4.google.com
        AAAA IPv6 address = 2001:4860:4802:38::a
        ttl = 160225 (1 day 20 hours 30 mins 25 secs)

------------
Non-authoritative answer:
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 5, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 4,  additional = 8

    QUESTIONS:
        google.com, type = AAAA, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  google.com
        AAAA IPv6 address = 2800:3f0:4004:808::200e
        ttl = 41 (41 secs)
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  google.com
        nameserver = ns1.google.com
        ttl = 6075 (1 hour 41 mins 15 secs)
    ->  google.com
        nameserver = ns3.google.com
        ttl = 6075 (1 hour 41 mins 15 secs)
    ->  google.com
        nameserver = ns4.google.com
        ttl = 6075 (1 hour 41 mins 15 secs)
    ->  google.com
        nameserver = ns2.google.com
        ttl = 6075 (1 hour 41 mins 15 secs)
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
    ->  ns1.google.com
        internet address = 216.239.32.10
        ttl = 92711 (1 day 1 hour 45 mins 11 secs)
    ->  ns2.google.com
        internet address = 216.239.34.10
        ttl = 92711 (1 day 1 hour 45 mins 11 secs)
    ->  ns3.google.com
        internet address = 216.239.36.10
        ttl = 19014 (5 hours 16 mins 54 secs)
    ->  ns4.google.com
        internet address = 216.239.38.10
        ttl = 19014 (5 hours 16 mins 54 secs)
    ->  ns1.google.com
        AAAA IPv6 address = 2001:4860:4802:32::a
        ttl = 160225 (1 day 20 hours 30 mins 25 secs)
    ->  ns2.google.com
        AAAA IPv6 address = 2001:4860:4802:34::a
        ttl = 160225 (1 day 20 hours 30 mins 25 secs)
    ->  ns3.google.com
        AAAA IPv6 address = 2001:4860:4802:36::a
        ttl = 160225 (1 day 20 hours 30 mins 25 secs)
    ->  ns4.google.com
        AAAA IPv6 address = 2001:4860:4802:38::a
        ttl = 160225 (1 day 20 hours 30 mins 25 secs)

------------
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2800:3f0:4004:808::200e
          142.250.79.14
```

---

Edit 2: Looks like it's related with a problem with the internal DNS server created for WSL, which is the internal Hyper-V DNS server, which is the Windows Internet Connection Sharing (ICS).

I found an open issue on WSL's GitHub with a lot of people complaining about the problem.

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5806

Comment: Google uses load balancing. Most websites do, so they rarely have, a singular address. These websites are not working or they are and your simply confused by the results?

Comment: The first `nslookup` in the question is right as you said, just load balancing. The second one is bringing IPs of the Nameservers, not the actual services. So when the requests are made not to the first IP, they fail. And I used Google only as a example here. Some URLs that I'm having problem doesn't even have load balancing.

Comment: can you show the `nslookup -d google.com` output? It really looks like a problem with your VPN network 1) intercepting and redirecting DNS requests 2) to a broken DNS server – not with your system.

Comment: @u1686_grawity, the question was updated with some debug data. I looks like `Authority` and `Additional` records are being merged in `Answer` when the request is made with WSL gateway as nameserver. I don't know whether it's supposed to be this way.